# Class in android library project extending another class in root project

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-library

I have an android project where I want to separate two modules by making one as a library project. But the class which will become a part of library extends a class which will be in the root project. So, how can I link these two in build.gradle?

Gradle file of root project contains:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        main.java.srcDirs = ['src']
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        proto.srcDirs 'protos/'
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile files('libs/host-libprotobuf-java-2.3.0-nano.jar')
    compile files('libs/protobuf-java-2.3.0.jar')
    compile project('lib')
}
```

The library project gradle file contains:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }
}
```

In this case, it shows error in 'lib' project where I am extending class of root project. If I modifiy java.srcDirs in library gradle file to

```
java.srcDirs = ['src', '../src']
```

the class gets extended without any compilation issues but gets issues in other classes of root project.

So, can anyone tell me how to link this two?

Answer (score 1):

Circular dependencies (of modules) are a really bad idea. You should always avoid them.

Solution:

- Move the base class to the library module or
- Create a third module for the base class and reference it from both other modules